# Sage 50 Accounting SDK Creating Sales Quotes with many Items

Tags: c#, sdk, quotes, sage-erp, sage50

I'm using the SAGE 50 Accounting SDK C# and I need to create Sales Quotes with Items. I already achieve to create the Sales Quote record and only 1 item, but if I want to add more than 1 item, seems like SAGE is creating one sales quote record with only one item. This is the code I'm using:

```
        TOSalesInvoiceCollection salesinvoiceCollection = new TOSalesInvoiceCollection();
        TOSalesInvoiceRowCollection items = new TOSalesInvoiceRowCollection();

        TOSalesInvoice salesinvoice = new TOSalesInvoice();
        salesinvoice.CustomerID = "4444";
        salesinvoice.Date = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        salesinvoice.IsQuote = true;
        salesinvoice.ARAccount = "11010";
        salesinvoice.NumberOfDistributions = 1;
        salesinvoice.Note = "Sales Quote created for Group: " + 1;
        salesinvoice.InternalNote = "NOTE YUCEL";

        TOSalesInvoiceRow line = new TOSalesInvoiceRow();
        line.GLAccount = "10090";
        line.ItemID = "WLL";
        line.Quantity = 1;
        decimal unitprice = 3433.20m;
        line.UnitPrice = unitprice;
        line.Amount = unitprice;
        line.JobID = "1";
        line.Description = "Line  ; AE01.22; Architectural and Engineering Drawing*";
        line.OrderDistributionNumber = 1;
        items.Add(line);

        TOSalesInvoiceRow line2 = new TOSalesInvoiceRow();
        line2.GLAccount = "10090";
        line2.ItemID = "0002";
        line2.Quantity = 1;
        decimal unitprice2 = 3433.20m;
        line2.UnitPrice = unitprice2;
        line2.Amount = unitprice2;
        line2.JobID = "1";
        line2.Description = "1-A FAA & FCC Required Coordinates Form";
        line2.OrderDistributionNumber =2;

        items.Add(line2);

        salesinvoice.RowCollection = items;

        salesinvoiceCollection.Add(salesinvoice);
        TOSalesInvoice.SaveAll(_boSalesInvoiceSettings, null, salesinvoiceCollection);
```

Is there anything in the code that I need to put both items in only 1 Sales Quote?

The result in SAGE looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, in this case **TOSalesInvoice NumberOfDistributions** should be set to the number of line items we want to set and at the sales quote line **OrderDistributionNumber** is like "Item Line number".

Comment: Hi @Yucel can you please guide me how to implement sage 50's COM api in a c# project. I have added one dll file (Sage.Sage50.ManagedCOM) which i got from sample code. After this i was started getting code hint for the classes in my code but when i debug my code it refer to the sample code itself. If you can provide me any documentation link where it guided properly that also will be a great help

Comment: Hi @HarishKumar, I have a repository with a solution to integrate Salesforce and use Sage50, basically one of the important things is to set a ODBC connection to pull the data using regular SQL queries, you can take as base the project and explore the code here's the repo: https://github.com/emoran/salesforce-SAGE50-Integration hope this helps.

Comment: yes i found this too in .net sdk. let me try this if it could help